# Flat file vs MySQL for very simple data

Tags: php, mysql, flat-file

From a pure performance standpoint what would you say is better for storing simple data (predefined messages).  Would you say it's more work to open a file handle, json_decode a "Subject" and a "body", and close the file or query a database (SELECT `subject`, `body` FROM `predefine` WHERE id='message1' assuming id is primary key).  I will only have 5-10 predefined messages however I want to assume that hundreds of users may be using this application concurrently.

Comment: For a few hundred users it won't matter. If I were using a db for other stuff i'd put the messages in the db as well

Comment: SQLite so you can use SQL on a self-contained file without a database server.

Answer (score 4):

Reading a flat file is extremely fast for small files... the performance advantages of databases come when you attempt to seek specific data. If you're just grabbing a specific file (say, based on filename: `msg_1.txt`, `msg_2.txt`, etc) you're going to be better off with a flatfile system.

That said, as JB Nizet has pointed out, if you're only dealing with a few messages don't bother... use a constant OR create an array in a PHP file that can be `include_once()`ed when you need the definition:

```
$msg = array(
  'msg1'=>array('sub'=>"subject",'body'=>"body Text"),
  'msg2'=>array('sub'=>"subject 2",'body'=>"body Text 2"),
  //...etc.
);
```

Comment: The predefined MAY be edited by the admin when he feels like changing them but that's obviously not much.  They are effectively read only.  I see MySQL kill servers all day and am worried about reducing CPU usage when not necessary.

Comment: For simple mysql queries with indexes and smallish tables, you're going to be dealing with query times in the low 10,000ths of a second range, so I doubt you'll hit any walls there (the server should be releasing the connect so fast that several hundred concurrent users shouldn't be a problem). You should look into a persistent connection, though, as the real time waster will be creating and dropping connections. However, in your situation (you know that you're always going to be accessing via a single key, ie. id or filename) I generally use flatfiles or predefined arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If the message is predefined and read-only, I would simply hard-code it (as a constant) into a PHP source file.

If it does change, let the database handle the concurrency issues. Reading a row by primary key is very fast, especially if there are only 10 rows in the table. That's probably not where your app will have a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

For 5-10 messages, the flat file is much more efficient. MySQL is a separate process, so simple cross process communication will cause more CPU load then parsing a small file. At 100 messages, I would start thinking about a more complex system, like a simply indexed file. Even then SQL is an overkill. You will start seeing benefits from databases only when you are at 10000 or 100000 messages.

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel said, if you're already using the DB then throw them in there. If your application is a daemon process, load them from the DB on restart and cache them in memory and this will guarantee the best performance.

Comment: Right. But then it's running in a web-server (apache maybe) and he can cache it there. For example if it were Django I'd use one of the cache backends.